# How to create 2 Image rotation carousels on the same page using one jquery script file

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

new to jquery need help please!!... - I'm trying  to create two carousels on the home page using the example below but doesn't seem to work.

I realise that the example is using ids, tried to change them to classes but didnt it do much.

http://www.dreamcss.com/2009/04/create-beautiful-jquery-sliders.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An important philosophy in jQuery is "Don't reinvent the wheel."

Just use a plugin for features like this, such as [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider)!

[Here's a demo of more than one on a single page](http://cssglobe.com/lab/easyslider1.7/03.html)

Oh, and in the future, be sure to describe *what* doesn't work as well as your code if you want people to actually be able to help you with your specific problem.

Comment: Thanks for that...Is there a way to get description on these sliders like one in my example you get the number of images in a slide and current slide highlight? sorry for not being descriptive with the error.

Comment: Did you go to my multi-slider demo I linked to?  The bottom one is numbered.

Comment: Yes multi-slider has 2 sliders on the same page, but those are different sliders...what i need is the same slider repeated twice ie the one with arrows on left and right side to be repeated twice, currently when I apply the code  


$("#slider2").easySlider({ 
  auto: true,
  continuous: true,
  nextId: "slider1next",
  prevId: "slider1prev"
        
 });


I get the top slide with the arrows and the bottom without.

Comment: Why would you define your left and right buttons on "slider2" to be `nextId: "slider1next", prevId: "slider1prev"`?  Clearly you also need to duplicate these buttons down as well and assign them to new IDs.

Comment: AH! thats great...is it also possible to get description panel on each image of the slider ?

Comment: Probably.  You'd just slide divs, not actual images.  Each div would contain an image and a description.  If you found this little discussion helpful, please mark my answer above as the solution by clicking the checkmark to the left of it so it's green.

Comment: thats cool...one more last thing please - when i duplicate the numeric slider 



  $(document).ready(function(){ 
   $("#slider").easySlider({
   
    continuous: true,
    numeric: true,

   });
   
   $("#slider2").easySlider({ 

    continuous: true,
    numeric: true,
   
   });
   
  }); 


The numbers for the second carousel do not have the highlight on them...also the numbers for the bottom carousel are positioned right after the numbers of the first carousel..